# Laravel 5.5: Use another table for authentication instead of 'users'

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.5

I want to use another table instead of `users` for authentication. I know I can change the table name in `User.php` as follows:

```
protected $table = 'WhatEver';
```

But this is not what I want. I want to change the name in the backend of the application so that a completely different model is used. How can I achieve that? What files do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. First create a new database table, which should have `password` and `remember_token` fields. In `config/auth.php` change the `providers` section as follows:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\NEW_MODEL_NAME::class,
],
```

After that, you need to alter `App/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php`:

```
protected function validator(array $data) {
return Validator::make($data, [
    'surname' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:NEW_DB_TABLE_NAME',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
}
protected function create(array $data) {
return App\NEW_MODEL_NAME::create([
    'surname' => $data['surname'],
    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
   ]);
}
```

That's it.